# How can get widget instance and call functions of widget in dojo2

Tags: dojo2

I create a dojo app with following render function.
...
    protected render() {

```
    let zombie = w(Zombie,{}); //zombie has a function walk();

    return v('div', [
        v('div',{
            style: "position: relative;height:500px;"
        },[
            zombie
        ])
    ])
}
```

...

And Zombie widget has a walk function.how and where can I call it from App?

Answer (score 0):

We actually can't call the child widget method, however we can call parent widget method from child widget by calling callbackFunction we passed in below code.

```
export default class DemoWidget extends WidgetBase {
  protected callbackFunction() {
    console.log("callbackFunction");
  }

  protected render() { 
    let zombie = w(Zombie,{
      callbackFunction: this.callbackFunction
     }); //zombie has a function walk(); 
    return v('div', 
         [ v('div',{ style: "position: relative;height:500px;" },
         [ zombie ]) ]) 
    }
  }
}
```